# Fast question: I want to know what class is my sd card? How to do?

Tags: sd-card

A fast question: I want to know what speed class is my sd card? How to do?
Using dmesg show those info

```
mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address 0001
```

is possible to know the speed class of a card from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me google that for you:

1. The only tool I'm aware of is [`f3`](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3) (Fight Flash Fraud) - available as a port (`sudo install f3`), or for download from GitHub & build the latest. I used it once some time ago; it seemed like a fairly solid app.
2. The SD Association maintains a website with all of the standards listed -  including the [`speed class`](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/sd-standard-overview/speed-class/).

You can therefore look at your card to get its claimed speed class, and then run `f3` to verify that.

`dmesg` has some useful info, but I don't recall it includes a speed rating.